# Access - Navigation Form Changes Record Source to Target Name and Unbinds Controls

Tags: vba, ms-access, unbound

I have a series of forms filtered using VBA all working fine until the forms are added to a Navigation form, then an error is returned saying ' The action or method is invalid because the form or report isn't bound to a table or query'

I think... its caused because the navigation form doesn't have a record source... instead it has a target name

On the original form the property record source is tblAvailableHours2

On the navigation form the property is target name Frm_Available_Capacity_Hours

*Its a simple date filter,*

```
Private Sub ApplyDtFilt_Click()

    On Error GoTo ApplyDtFilt_Click_Err
    
     DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Start Date] Between #" & Format([AVstrtdt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([AVEnDt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
     
    ApplyDtFilt_Click_Exit:
        Exit Sub
    ApplyDtFilt_Click_Err:
        MsgBox Error$
        Resume ApplyDtFilt_Click_Exit
    
End Sub
```

Is there way of linking the above filter back to the original table tblAvailableHours2 in VBA or manipulating the navigation form record source/target name in the property sheet to get it working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using the navigation forms, but if your form is a subform, you must address this via the subform control holding it:

```vb
Private Sub ApplyDtFilt_Click()

    On Error GoTo ApplyDtFilt_Click_Err

    With Me!NameOfSubformControlHoldingFrm_Available_Capacity_Hours.Form
        .Filter = "[Start Date] Between #" & Format([AVstrtdt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([AVEnDt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
        .FilterOn = True
    End With
     
    ApplyDtFilt_Click_Exit:
        Exit Sub
    ApplyDtFilt_Click_Err:
        MsgBox Error$
        Resume ApplyDtFilt_Click_Exit
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It would appear to be Gustav to my rescue again... Your answer sent me in the right direction... thanks very much! It through up an error as couldn't find the subform Frm_Available_Capacity_Hours however researching this approach the correct way to do it with a navigation form is to call up the name of the navigation form. In this case it was EPM-V2...With Forms![EPM-V2]![NavigationSubform].Form.....  (I'll post the final code below in case anyone else is looking) Thanks for helping out ;-) Time for a coffee!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ApplyDtFilt_Click()
On Error GoTo ApplyDtFilt_Click_Err
     
     With Forms![EPM-V2]![NavigationSubform].Form
     Filter = "[Start Date] Between #" & Format([AVstrtdt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([AVEnDt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
    .FilterOn = True
    End With

ApplyDtFilt_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub
ApplyDtFilt_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume ApplyDtFilt_Click_Exit
End Sub
```